# Shopify - Forgot password / reset password not working

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to add a Forgot/Reset Password link to my Shopify page.

I tried this:

```
<a href="/account/login#recover">reset</a>
```

But **/account/login#recover** link brings me to the login page instead of to Forgot/Reset Password page.

What is the right URL for going directly to Forgot/Reset Password page?

Comment: What is the direct link to the page?

Comment: Does it make any difference? Shouldn't <a href="/account/login#recover">reset</a> show the reset password page?

Comment: I have meant with the full base url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct url which one you are using. Actually forgot password form is also on the same page as login. It is hiding and showing Login/Forgot-Password based on url parameters.